# Angular 4 dynamic components with dynamic routing throwing an error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this routing configuration coming from a server and loaded before the application bootstrap:

config.json

```
[{
  "path": "dashboard",
  "component": "SingleComponent",
  "data": {...}
},
{
  "path": "payment",
  "roles": ["normal-user"],
  "children": [{
    "path": "new",
    "component": "SingleComponent",
    "data": {...}
    }
  }]
}
```

```

where `"SingleComponent"` is replaced with the reference of the class before calling `router.resetConfig(loadedRoutes);`
until now everything's ok, if I load the `/dashboard` the page is loading correctly (I needed to put the component reference into the `@NgModule.entryComponents` because there's no reference to that component elsewhere.

If I navigate to `/payment/new` i get this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for SingleComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for SingleComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3898)
at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:3962)
at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:6652)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5735)
at eval (router.js:5675)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.js:5674)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5742)
at eval (router.js:5675)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3898)
at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:3962)
at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:6652)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5735)
at eval (router.js:5675)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.js:5674)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5742)
at eval (router.js:5675)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
at eval (zone.js:873)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

but actually that's my module:

```
...

  entryComponents: [ // components used by remote loaded routes
    SingleComponent,
  ],
})
```

what's happening? any ideas?
I couldn't find any documentation about this error

angular is version `5.0.0`

Comment: can you provide a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

is it declared component at @NgModule?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    SingleComponent,
    ...
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that during the parsing the `component` property of children routes wasn't set correctly, solving that issue solved the problem